# How can I adjust the spacing command to accommodate different spacing between text and tables?

Tags: floats

I am using the commands below taken from a cls file to adjust spacing between text in my document. However, I want to undo these commands when I come to the tables part of the document. So I wish to keep the standard spacing between tables and only adjust it for the text. Please let me know how to accomplish this. Many thanks.

```
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.39in}
  \setlength{\parskip}{18pt}
  \newcommand{\spacing}[1]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}\large\normalsize}
  \spacing{2}
```

Comment: I know machines are faster than they used to be but why would you ever want to do `\large\normalsize` other tahn to slow things down?

Comment: You should probably be using the `setspace` package instead which provides commands for double spacing the main text and tries to reset it in places to reduce the damage this causes.

Comment: I am just using this cls file for the journal Nature available through CTAN so not sure how efficient it is. Could you help me with spacing adjustment though?

Comment: the `\large` does _absolutely nothing_ so efficiency does not really come in to it:-) as I say use the `setspace` package, which has already done the work of patching floats etc to return to normal spacing.

Comment: Or if you are really forced to use that class, just issue `\spacing{1}` after each `\begin{table}`

Comment: Thanks David! It worked. I was just hesitant to modify a given cls file

Answer (score 1):

First your method.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.39in}
  \setlength{\parskip}{18pt}
  \newcommand{\spacing}[1]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}}
  \spacing{2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\spacing{1}}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.9\linewidth}}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Here we use `etoolbox` package to insert the command `\spacing{1}` inside every table.

Or the easy method (As David says)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing         %% or \setstretch{2}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.9\linewidth}}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

With `setspace`, you don't have to do anything as things are already taken care of. So follow this method.